# Ubuntu Software vs manual download from a developer site? What's the best way to install a program?

Tags: ubuntu, snap

As far as I know, programs from Ubuntu Software store are snap-based and I heard that snaps are slower than .deb and other methods. But it installs the updates automatically, and if I install from a developer's site, there is no auto-update. Am I correct? What do you recommend? I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, the Ubuntu Software app shows both snaps and debs. And the usual repositories are as they always were so you can install anything with a simple command as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you [add the repository of the software as a ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox), then when you choose to update Ubuntu, those applications would also be updated.

For example, Ubuntu is *slow* to update the Thunderbird mail client, even when security changes are needed. To add Mozillla *Thunderbird*'s repository, in terminal enter the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

Now, if you open the Ubuntu *Software & Updates* settings, on the *Other Software* tab, *mozillateam* should show.

Yes, Ubuntu is leaning towards providing *everything* though Snap, which I find objectionable for a few reasons:

- Snap updates include *every* dependency, so are *huge* compared to just updating a package.
- Snap updates occur automatically, with no user control.
- Some Snap applications are updated far less frequently than the actual package repository, leaving applications such as *Thunderbird* less secure.

Of course, adding a ppa has its own disadvantage: **You're trusting the ppa to provide safe software, without Ubuntu vetting.**

So it's your choice which way to add software.

Answer (score 0):

I used to prefer adding a repository so I can use apt or whatever package management available. I really don't like Ubuntu Software although it is just a re-branded snap store with a repository (snapcraft.io)

But snap apps are generally isolated so apps can run arbitrary code in your computer. It is true that not all apps are build with this security layer and it's also true that some apps doesn't work well like this (Firefox never find my cryptographic devices for example).

There is another problem that made me give up from Ubuntu Store. The software there is often too old.

So I installed Snap ans it's repository and now in Snap Store I have access to snapcraft.io, flathub.org and deb packages. As ChanganAuto said, the Ubuntu Software already shows snaps and debs.

As DrMoishe Pippik said, with these approaches you have update delivery. But if you install from sources, or by unpacking a tar or even by running a .deb, you will need manual updates.